# How to check Uris for equality excluding the query part?

Tags: c#, uri

The default [`Uri.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f83xtf15.aspx) method only ignores user information (`UserInfo`) and the fragment (`Fragment`).

Is there any method that compares for equality and ignores `Query` as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Uri.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.compare) allows you to specify which parts should be involved in the comparison by passing in a [`UriComponents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7767559y) value.